# Перенаправление портов nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

В общем, есть у меня сервер **ubuntu** 18.04.2 LTS и на нём стоит **nginx**.
**Nginx**  у меня уже запущен и при переходе на публичный айпи сервера видно стартовую страницу.

Так же у меня есть сервер на **NodeJS**, который занимает порт **8080**. Выглядит это так:
88.99.88.99:8080 *(айпи не мой, это для примера)*.

Как сделать так чтобы **88.99.88.99:8080** стало **88.99.88.99/server** с помощью **nginx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В секцию server{} добавить:

```
location /server {
    proxy_pass http://88.99.88.99:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```